# WCF service returns error 500 on /js request

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis

I have a wcf service that randomly begins to fail, when requesting the autogenerated javascript that wcf supports in making. But I have no luck tracking down why,the js thing is part of the wcf featureset.So I dont know how it can suddenly begin to fail and be unable to work until IIS is recycled.

The http log gives me:

```
2010-06-10 09:11:49 W3SVC2095255988 myip GET /path/myservice.svc/js _=1276161113900 80 - ip browser 500 0 0
```

So its an error 500, and that is about the only thing I can figure out. The event log contains no information.

Requests to /path/myservice.svc works just fine. After recycling IIS it works again, and some days later it begins to fail until I recycle IIS.

```
     <service
        name="path.myservice"
        behaviorConfiguration="b">
        <endpoint
           address=""
           behaviorConfiguration="eb"
           binding="webHttpBinding"
           contract="path.Imyservice" />
     </service>
     ...
     <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="eb">
           <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
     </endpointBehaviors>
     <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="b">
           <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
           <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
           <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
     </serviceBehaviors>
```

I dont see any problems in the web.config settings either.

Any clues how I can track down what the problem is?

**Edit:**

Just to make it clear - It is the generation of javascript that fails, my code is never invoked. Calls to the service works just fine.

Comment: No, it went away by itself. Still have no clue what caused it, or what made it go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to [enable tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) in your service and look at the generated logs with [Service Trace Viewer Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx). Trace only errors to keep your logs small.

Comment: It doesnt actually fail on doing what I coded it to do. It fails to deliver the javascript I need to do easy code. If I do the calls directly, they work fine

Comment: That's why I suggested you enabling tracing. Tracing does not log only errors coming from your code - it will log all errors.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your WCF Service throws an Exception. You can catch this unhandled Exception in the Application_Error method in Global.asax, than write it to a log file.

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
    //TODO: write to log
}
```

Comment: no, it never enters my code. It is the microsoft generation of javascript that fails. Calls to the service works just fine. And if it came to this code, I would have gotten a nice email with the details and wouldnt have to ask here :)